# Plot data/samples on the map

Tags: python, dictionary, plot

What I am doing wrong here? I want to plot samples/data on top of my map(pixel plot).I have two different input data- one is for drawing a contour line, and another one I am using to plot samples on top of that contour map.

It can be seen here:

[image: My code]